# Why the emitter is earthed in the Common-Emitter configuration of a Transistor?

Tags: transistors, configuration

While reading the Common-Emitter configuration of a Transistor from a book, they said that the Emitter is *earthed*...? Then I Googled it and found the same thing... So my question is that why it is necessary to earth the Emitter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm5Njf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Earth" or "ground" in this case just means the point in the circuit the designer decided to call "zero volts", and use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit - it does not imply an actual connection to the earth.  I'd prefer to call that point "circuit ground", or "common", rather than "earth".

The important thing to notice in a common emitter circuit is that the emitter is common to both the input and output sides of the circuit